# Strange performance behavior

Tags: c#, .net, string, performance

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 SP1, Target framework is 2.0, Platform target: Any CPU, testing under Windows 7 x64 SP1.

I'm experiencing strange performance behavior.

Without an app.config, or with the following app.config, it makes my program run slowly (Stopwatch shows ~0.11 s)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup >
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

The following app.config makes my program run x5 times faster (Stopwatch shows ~0.02 s)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup >
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

This is the test program code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        while (true)
        {
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++ )
            {
                "blablabla".IndexOf("ngrhotbegmhroes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sitting for hours and can't figure out what is happening here.
Have you any idea?

Comment: The System.String class itself was changed in .NET 4.  With plenty of work on the NLS bits in the CLR.  You cannot reasonably expect similar outcomes, only hope.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It sounds like you've just found a situation in which .NET 4 is a lot faster. By default, your app is running with the framework it was built to target. When you *force* it to use .NET 4, it's faster. That may be a JIT compiler improvement which happens to hit your situation, or it may be a framework improvement - but it shouldn't be too surprising that some things are faster in newer versions.

(For what it's worth, I'd increase the number of iterations you're timing over if I were you... on my box under .NET 4, each iteration is only 10ms, which isn't really a great measurement. I prefer to benchmark for at least a few seconds.)

(And like Mitch, I can confirm that I see the same effect.)

EDIT: I've just investigated this a bit further, and seen an interesting effect... I'll assume we're calling `haystack.IndexOf(needle, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`:

- On .NET 2, the results are roughly the same however big the "needle" is
- On .NET 4:

  - If `needle` is bigger than `haystack` (as per your example) .NET 4 is much faster than .NET 2
  - If `needle` is the same size as `haystack`, .NET 4 is a *little* bit slower than .NET 2
  - If `needle` is smaller than `haystack`, .NET 4 is a *lot* slower than .NET 2

(This is keeping a test where the first character of `needle` never appears in `haystack`, btw.)

Comment: Shouldn't "When you force it to use .NET" read "When you force it to use .NET **4**"?

Comment: "If needle is smaller than haystack, .NET 4 is a lot slower" - seems like a very poor optimization then.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Indeed. I had to rush off after testing that - if you (or someone else) could reproduce it, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran your benchmark with a few tweaks (which included more iterations and averaging), and can confirm that the .NET 4.0 targeted version is indeed 4-5 times faster.

So presumably `IndexOf()` was optimised in .NET 4.0

Answer (score 3):

OK, some benchmarks with the new VS11

```
n = 1000000;
string haystack = "ngrhotbegmhroes";
string needle = "blablablablablablablablablangrhotbegmhrobla bla";

.NET 4.5 :  8 ms
.NET 4.0 :  8 ms
.NET 3.5 : 45 ms
.NET 2.0 : 45 ms
```

So these first results confirm your findings, the newer versions are faster.

It is however much more common to look for s short string inside a larger string:

```
n = 1000000; 
haystack = "blablablablablablablablablangrhotbegmhrobla bla";  
needle = "ngrhotbegmhroes";

.NET 4.5 : 1020 ms
.NET 4.0 : 1020 ms
.NET 3.5 :  155 ms
.NET 2.0 :  155 ms
```

And with a much longer haystack (~400 chars)

```
.NET 4.0 : 12100 ms
.NET 2.0 :  1700 ms
```

Which means things got worse for the most common use pattern...

---

All measurements in Release config, and Client Profile where available.
Running from VS 11 with Ctrl+F5
Win 7H, Core i7 2620M

Comment: wow - this is really strange - wonder if some internal to the CLR/BCL could say something about this...

Comment: What's even the point of searching for a long needle in a short haystack? Isn't this FALSE by design?

Comment: @yas4891: Yes, but it was the original question and it has very different performance.

Comment: Fwiw, .NET 4.5 is not side-by-side, it overwrites .NET 4.0.  Same thing with .NET 3.5 vs 2.0.  That's why the timings are the same.  Careful with 4.5, with it in pre-release and whacking 4.0 you can't draw any real conclusions.

Comment: @Hans, OK, I only knew about 3.5/2.0 . Should read up on 4.5.